# Using a specific base layer in a Python Plotly/Flask form

Tags: flask, maps, plotly-python

I have a Flask app with some forms that display maps. I'm using plotly_exress.choropleth_mapbox to do that.

Now I need to change the base map to use a specific layer as shown in https://www.icgc.cat/en/Public-Administration-and-Enterprises/Services/Online-services-Geoservices/Services-for-APIs-and-Widgets/API-de-Mapbox.

How can I do that?

Comment: the documentation for how to add layers is good: https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/.  if it is something far more specific - make question far more specific

Comment: Tks, Rob, you're right. I could use this example and solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the following instruction to my map routine and it worked:

```
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_style="white-bg",
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "below": 'traces',
            "sourcetype": "raster",
            "sourceattribution": "Institut Cartogràfic i Geològic de Catalunya",
            "source": [
                "https://geoserveis.icgc.cat/icc_mapesmultibase/noutm/wmts/topo/GRID3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg"
            ]
        }
    ])
```

[image]